# taking the average of a column in RDD-spark-scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a dataset like below. I just need to know how to get the average of physics marks for the whole students in a class. using spark+scala whithout using dataframe.

header

```
name|physics|biology
ram|30|40
sam|35|45
ravi|37|44
```

outout should be something like

`physics|34`

Thanks in advance.....

Comment: i tried using rdd.map() function but didnt get the desired result

Comment: https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/ Will help you ask the question so we can see how to help ... provide sample data, code tried.

Comment: For your tasnknis better to use spark dataframes and youncan put the column when doing the average.

Comment: but i need to do it without dataframe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you got a RDD[String] as

```
val rdd = sparkContext.parallelize(Seq(
    ("ram|30|40"),
    ("sam|35|45"),
    ("ravi|37|44")
  ))
```

then

```
//split and select three columns 
val average = rdd.map(_.split("\\|")).map(x => (x(0), x(1), x(2)))
              //calculate the mean of third column
              .map(_._2.toInt).mean()
```

This will give you he value `34.0`

or you could just do as

```
rdd.map(_.split("\\|")).map(_(1).toInt).mean()
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can filter out the physics column from your `Dataset` and then find the average using either of these two ways.

```
//first create your dataset
case class Result(name:String,physics:Int,biology:Int)
val ds = spark.createDataset(Array(Result("ram",30,40),Result("sam",35,45),Result("ravi",37,44)))

ds.show

//+----+-------+-------+
//|name|physics|biology|
//+----+-------+-------+
//| ram|     30|     40|
//| sam|     35|     45|
//|ravi|     37|     44|
//+----+-------+-------+
```

Now one way is you can filter physics column and then convert to `RDD` and apply `mean` function to that as follow,

```
ds.map(_.physics).rdd.mean
//34.0
```

If you don't want to convert to RDD then you can do something like,

```
val physics = ds.map(_.physics)
val avg = physics.reduce(_+_)/physics.count
//34
```